# Loss function giving nan in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

In pytorch, I have a loss function of `1/x` plus a few other terms. The last layer of my neural net is a sigmoid, so the values will be between 0 and 1.

Some value fed to `1/x` must get really small at some point because my loss has become this:

```bash
loss: 11.047459  [729600/235474375]
loss: 9.348356  [731200/235474375]
loss: 7.184393  [732800/235474375]
loss: 8.699876  [734400/235474375]
loss: 7.178806  [736000/235474375]
loss: 8.090066  [737600/235474375]
loss: 12.415799  [739200/235474375]
loss: 10.422441  [740800/235474375]
loss: 8.335846  [742400/235474375]
loss:     nan  [744000/235474375]
loss:     nan  [745600/235474375]
loss:     nan  [747200/235474375]
loss:     nan  [748800/235474375]
loss:     nan  [750400/235474375]
```

I'm wondering if there's any way to "rewind" if `nan` is hit or define the loss function so that it's never hit? Thanks!

Comment: To handle NaN values during training, you can use PyTorch's NaN-aware optimizer, such as torch.optim.AdamW with the torch.optim.swa_utils.AveragedModel wrapper. This optimizer automatically detects NaN values and skips the current batch, effectively "rewinding" the training process to the previous batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loss is jumping all over the place instead of steadily decreasing. Have you tried decreasing your learning rate? It looks like it's jumping across the minimum, bouncing back and forth. This can happen if the learning rate is too high.

To answer your question about rewinding, ideally you shouldn't have to rewind, the loss should be steadily decreasing. Also you may want to look into [learning rate schedulers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau).

[image: why the learning rate needs tuned]

Comment: One interesting phenomenon is that the learning rate feels "just right" (Adam that's steadily decreasing) until around the millionth data point, and then the system goes too close to 0 for the 1/x term and never recovers.

```bash
loss: 0.006247  [1374400/235474375]
loss: 0.035386  [1376000/235474375]
loss: 0.069158  [1377600/235474375]
loss: 0.011270  [1379200/235474375]
loss: 0.369613  [1380800/235474375]
loss: 0.573851  [1382400/235474375]
loss: 1.363750  [1384000/235474375]
loss: 5.718307  [1385600/235474375]
loss: 27.132248  [1387200/235474375]
```

Comment: @Mike In my experience, Adam can act a little unpredictable sometimes (though it often works like great). Maybe you could try standard SGD with a learning scheduler? I like ReduceLROnPlateau, it might work for your purpose.

Comment: Oh wow SGD with a sloowww learning rate did it! Didn't even need to use a scheduler. Adam can't recover from the spikey gradient towards 0 for some reason.

Comment: @Mike Glad it worked for you. I wonder if it has anything to do with floating point number accuracy shenanigans. Maybe something that Adam is doing is causing floating point underflow? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow

Answer (score 3):

Clip your loss to fall within a reasonable range to prevent gradient explosion (i.e. continually climbing out of the local neighborhood as in BrockBrown's answer.)

I'd recommend something like this:

```
 epsilon = 1e-01
 loss = 1/(x + epsilon) # bounded maximum value of 10
```

or:

```
 eta = 5 # maximum loss value
 loss = torch.clamp(loss,max = eta)
```

As a third option, you can simply check for `nan` values and not backpropagate in these cases. This won't help with stability, it will just remove outlier loss values, but you still may not get good convergence properties depending on the nature of when these values occur.

```
 if (loss.isnan.sum() == 0): # no nan values 
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()
```

I'd also note that if your loss is `1/x`, and x is bounded between 0 and 1, you can't ever achieve a loss less than 1. Generally your loss should be 0 for a perfect output. Combining this fact with the previous ideas:

```
loss = 1/(epsilon + x) - (1/(1+epsilon))
```

When x = 1, loss approaches 0 , and when x = 0, loss is approximately 1/epsilon. You can adjust epsilon to attenuate your loss within a desired range for stability.